# Incompatible block pointer types sendeing 'void(^)(nsurlrequest)?

Tags: ios7, afnetworking, xcode5

In my app I am using AFNetwork to call services. This is the first time I am using AFNetwork. When I try to do the code by seeing some tutorials I am getting some errors:

```
Incompatible block Types sending `void(^)(NSUrlRequest* _strong)…`
```

My code is

```
  NSString *weatherUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherUrl];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  // 2
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
  [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
  // 3
      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
          self.weather  = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
          self.title = @"JSON Retrieved";
          [self.tableView reloadData];
      }
  // 4
      failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
          UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                       message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [av show];
      }];

  // 5
  [operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that there would be a to... portion of the error message like incompatible block pointer type sending --- to ----. Do you have the rest of the message?

**Recommendation**

You can check out Apple's [short practical guide on blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009758). Typically the incompatible... type errors means that a variable (block in this case) is improperly formed. The best way to solve this issue is to use blocks in different scenarios and improve your ability to see precisely where the problem is being generated. The code fragment you have provided does not show me enough information to answer the question directly. So here is a quick example of how I might use a block when doing a callback:

```
Class A.h

typedef void (^CallbackBlock)();

@interface Class A : <NSObject>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CallbackBlock onSomethingHappened;
...
@end


ClassA.m

@implementation ClassA

-(void) someMethod
{
    ... (after some work done)
    self.onSomethingHappened(); //this will notify any observers 
}
...
@end

ClassB.h

#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassB:UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic)ClassA * referenceToClassA;
@end

ClassB.m

@implementation ClassB

//! Can also be some other method in the lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    __weak ClassB *weakSelf = self;
    self.referenceToClassA.onSomethingHappened = ^(){ [weakSelf SomeMethodWithWorkTodoAfterSomethingHappened]; };

}
...
- (void)SomeMethodWithWorkTodoAfterSomethingHappened
{
    ...do some work after receiving callback from ClassA
}

@end
```

**Samples**

You can review the following [blog post](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/09/21/c-slash-objc-c-block-syntax-explained/) which covers typecasting with blocks. Your error seems to be complaining about a type casting problem with the block. If you cannot resolve please post a more complete error message and I will take another look. I've included the sample because it forced me to think through the problem.